# How to set different colors for shape's stroke (top/right/bottom/left)?

Tags: android, android-layout

Now I set one color for stroke, so it is used for 4 sides.
I'm trying to set different colors for each side of stroke.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#C7C7C7" />

</shape>
```

Here is how it can be achieved in css.

```
border-color:red green blue pink;
/*top border is red
right border is green
bottom border is blue
left border is pink*/
```

How to do the same in Android?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use layer list  for Implementing it
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList